# Balanced Data Distributor Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, balanced-data-distributor

I am working with SQL Server 2014 SP3 x64 and i have installed the cumulative update 1.
I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional and SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio and it works perfectly *(I can design an run SSIS packages without any issue)*.

I downloaded SSIS Balanced Data Distributor for the following Microsoft download Links:

- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 SP2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53164&44F86079-8679-400C-BFF2-9CA5F2BCBDFC=1)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

When I run the installation packages (both x64 and x86 - from both links), I get the following Error:

> Problem with this windows installer package. A program run as part of the installation did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor

I tried to [run the .msi as administrator from cmd](https://www.projectinsight.net/support/kb/installing-msi-files-as-an-administrator) with no luck. *(I am a member of administrators)*

I also checked the following link [Problem in Installing the Balanced data Distributor for SSIS 2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3a996f2-486f-451e-9f40-c1ec804fb87a/problem-in-installing-the-balanced-data-distributor-for-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices) which is about the same error, but i think this is a different situtation.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Are you an administrator on your machine?

Comment: @billinkc Yes, and i tried to run the `.msi` package as administrator as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: A non-administrator can attempt to run something as administrator but then get rejected by UAC or UAC gets swallowed and you think you're doing it in admin mode

Comment: @billinkc even if i am a member of administrators??

Comment: @billinkc i think you were right, i solved the issue by extracting the package components and perform the installation manually. i provided a detailed answer on that. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step-by-Step solution

1. First I executed  the `.msi` package with logging

   ```
   msiexec /i BalancedDistributor-amd64.msi /l*v "install.log"
   ```
2. I checked the log file untill i found the following error:

> MSI (s) (5C:EC) [12:32:01:306]: Product: Microsoft Balanced Data Distributor for SQL Server 2014 (x64) -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the installation did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action RegisterBDD32, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents\, command: regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents\TxBDD.dll"

Which means that the package encountered an error during the Dll registration.

3. I extracted the `.msi` package using 7zip , and it contains two files `BDDDll32` and `BDDDll64`
4. I renamed these files to `TxBDD.dll` *(from the installation log this is the original name of the DLL)*
5. I copy the files to the following directories:

   ```
   32-bit >> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents
   64-bit >> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents
   ```
6. After that i started cmd as Administrator and i executed the following commands:

   ```
   regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents\TxBDD.dll
   regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\PipelineComponents\TxBDD.dll
   ```
7. After that i started Visual Studio and on SSIS toolbox i click Refresh Items, and the `Balanced Data Distributor` is shown.

*Side Note: After checking the Event Viewer >> Windows Log >> Application, i also found the Error message listed above*

## References

- [How to extract msi files to your computer](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/08/extract-msi-files-computer/)
- [How to see the log files of msi package installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1299491/how-to-see-the-log-files-of-msi-package-installation)
- [Adding Custom Components to SSIS](http://agilebi.com/mcole/2009/08/18/adding-custom-components-to-ssis/)

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the above error installing BDD recently on Windows 2012R2 64-bit with SQL 2014 SP3.

I tried the above solutions and still received the error.  Found that when SQL2014 was installed the Shared Components Management Tools -Basic and Management Tools -Complete were not installed.

After adding these Shared Components to the SQL 2014 install, BDD installed successfully.

The Management Tools installs these programs which are apparently needed for BDD:

*.Net 4.0 Multi Targeting Pack*

[image: .Net 4.0 Multi Targeting Pack]

*Visual Studio 2010 Shell*

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Shell]

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this.